# Angular moment am-time-ago displays incorrect dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

When I use the am-time-ago directive like this `<span am-time-ago="feed.date | date"></span>` It displays times like `'in an hour'`. I've tried different filters but it doesn't seem to work. Here's an example of my database time `"2017-01-10T12:29:46.899850Z"`

Comment: You probably need to include `moment-timezone` and configure your timezone.

Comment: @kuhnroyal How do i do that? I tried this ` office.constant('moment', require('moment-timezone'));` but it ran into errors

Comment: This is only for webpack. Look at the bottom of the page, don't forget to include the JS file. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#time-zone-support

Comment: Ok after I do that what next?

Comment: Well... you configure your timezone, as described in the link. Your database time is in UTC and angular-moment will convert it to the one you configured. Without more information on your environment there is not much help anyone can provide.

Comment: @HackAfro what happens if you remove angular `date` filter (`am-time-ago="feed.date`")? can you provide a fiddle or a snippet showing your issue? Your database time is a string?

Comment: The anuglar moment filter basically displays time an hour ahead of my timezone(Lagos). I'm creating a fiddle, will include a link soon.